# SSH and VPN Cisco connection working on one laptop but not on another. Both laptops using Ubuntu 14.04. Where is the difference?

Tags: networking, wireless, server, ssh, vpn

I'm trying to SSH to our university server using VPN and WIFI connection.

The bug is similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437811/cannot-connect-to-university-computer-via-ssh-over-a-vpn-connection-to-my-uni-n), although different in details.

The problem is as follows:

Me and my colleague are using Ubuntu 14.04 on two different laptops.

I can SSH to the server using his laptop and my SSH login details, but not with my laptop and my SSH login details. We are both using VPN connected to the same WIFI (eduroam) network and we are in the same office. Configuration files /etc/sysctl.conf and /etc/ssh/ssh_config are identical on both laptops. Both of us are using Cisco VPNC plugin, which is required to connect to our VPN network.

WIFI and VPN connections work fine on both laptops. Both laptops say that VPN is successfully established, and the lock appears on the WIFI icon on the top-right corner of the screen.

But when I try to ssh to the cluster from my laptop I get the following message:

```
ssh: connect to host “xxx” port 22: Connection timed out
```

More information which may be useful to describe the problem:

1. My laptop can ssh to the required server when it is connected via
   LAN to the local network, but again cannot connect to the cluster
   when it is connected via WIFI and VPN.
2. I can successfully ping to the server from my laptop while using
   WIFI connection, both with and without using VPN.
3. My colleague cannot ssh to the cluster using his SSH details and my
   laptop. He gets the same message port 22: Connection time out.
4. My laptop can successfully SSH to another server while using my WIFI
   (eudoram) connection. But this server is different from the one I want
   to SSH and it belongs to another university which does not require
   VPN.
5. I have tried to reinstall packages `network-manager-vpnc` and `openssh-client`. None of these helped. Restarting did not help.

`nmap` Gives:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at “xxx”
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.06 seconds
```

`nmap -Pn` Gives:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at “xxx”
Nmap scan report for ...
Host is up.
All 1000 scanned ports on “xxx” are filtered

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 201.43 seconds
```

`ssh -vvv “xxx”` Gives

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to “xxx” [“xxx”] port 22.
debug1: connect to address “xxx” port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host “xxx” port 22: Connection timed out
```

1. What is wrong with the configuration of my Ubuntu?
2. What other configuration files (such as `/etc/sysctl.conf` or
       `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`) can I compare with the files of my colleague's
       laptop to find out what is different?
3. How can I test that the VPN connection works apart from seeing the
       lock on the top-right corner indicating that the VPN is active?

Comment: Have you tried `ssh -v xxx`? Or even `ssh -vvv xxx`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried `ssh -vvv xxx` now, with the result shown above.

Answer (score 3):

To connect to vpnc without using the vpnc manager install vpnc using

```
sudo apt-get install vpnc
```

Then create a file `mycnf.conf` containing the following information

```
IPSec gateway xx.xx.xx.xx
IPSec ID xxx
IPSec secret xxx
Xauth username xxx.xxx
Xauth password xxx
```

where `xxx` need to be replaced by your network and account details.
You may not need to use all the settings (all the lines), 
or you may need to add more settings (more lines) into that file.
This depends on your network properties.

Then replace the default vpnc configration file by running

```
sudo mv mycnf.conf /etc/vpnc/default.conf
```

Then connect with

```
sudo vpnc-connect
```

To disconnect use

```
sudo vpnc-disconnect
```

This does not give the answer to the question, but it provides a solution to the problem. Apparently, there is something going wrong with the vpnc manager based on package `network-manager-vpnc`. Unfortunately, I was not able to find what. Also, note that this answer has already been posted here: [CISCO VPN configuration steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488435/cisco-vpn-configuration-steps). What is new here is that `network-manager-vpnc` may not work whereas `vpnc` may do.

Answer (score -2):

1. No idea.
2. There are lots. `man ssh` lists some (`~/.ssh/config` comes to mind). Others can be discovered using e.g. `dpkg -L network-manager-vpnc`, which lists all the files installed by that package. You'll have to figure out which ones are config files.
3. Try https://dnsleaktest.com/. I think it's mainly aimed at people trying to steal movies safely, but I think it'll work for you.

Comment: 1. Sorry, if the question is too general. 2. My `~/.ssh` folder only contains file called `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, the suggested file  `~/.ssh/config` is not present.

Comment: 3.  Both me and my colleague tried to use dnsleaktest.com (advanced option), on our machines with VPN turned on and off, and also with LAN connection instead od Wifi connection. We did not obseve any differences in the list of Hostnames.

Comment: 2.  I've also tried to use `dpkg -L network-manager-vpnc` and compared files  `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/nm-vpnc-service.conf` and files `/etc/NetworkManager/VPN/nm-vpnc-service.name` which are identical to the ones of my coleague's laptop. I've also used `dpkg -L openssh-client`, but I've not found any relevant configuration files apart from the ones listed above.

Comment: I assume you checked that your colleage doesn't have a `~/.ssh/config` either.

Comment: I don't know exactly how it works, but when you first connected to the vpn, you probably auto-created config files somehow under something like `/etc/vpnc`. These will be different from your colleage's, but there may be some clues there.

Comment: Yes, I've double-checked that file `~/.ssh/config` does not exist on my colleage's machine.

Comment: The directory `/etc/vpnc`  contains two files: `/etc/vpnc/default.conf` and `/etc/vpnc/vpnc-script`. Both were identical on both machines.

Comment: Now, I've also tried to re-install network manager according to the instructions here: (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2239214)

Comment: Also, I un-installed vpnc modules using scripts: `sudo apt-get purge vpnc
`;`sudo apt-get purge network-manager-openvpn`;  as well as as my ssh client `sudo apt-get purge openssh-client`

Comment: And installed agained: `sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome`; `sudo apt-get install vpnc`; `sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc`; `sudo apt-get install openssh-client`

Comment: Now, since I used `purge` option  I would have thought that I would need to set-up my personal account settings again, (such as my network username, password, etc.) But Ubuntu retains these outside the `purge` option, i.e., `purge` option does not delete account settings. Where are my account settings stored?

Comment: Maybe I should open a new ubuntu question on stackexchange, since I'm trying to reinstall all my network settings and not to compare with the laptop of my colleague anymore?

Comment: I've just got a new laptop and installed Ubuntu 14.04 and all its updates. Before trying to install anything else, I tried to test vpnc. I followed [these steps](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488435/cisco-vpn-configuration-steps), which really just install `network-manager-vpnc`. I try to ssh to the sever. Unfortunatelly, I'm getting the same problem as I described above.

Comment: The Ubuntu installation was from a different USB stick and downloaded from a different depository.  I also tried yet another laptop with a new Ubuntu installation, the problem was the same. Again, I could ssh from my colleage laptop running 14.04 Ubuntu. Am I missing something more fundamental? My impression is that VPNC pretends to work (lock in the WiFi network icon) but it actually does not work. How shall I check/test that VPNC works properly on my laptop(s)?

Comment: I've asked a [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/680475/how-to-check-that-vpnc-vpn-cisco-works-on-ubuntu-14-04?lq=1) regarding the VPNC connection test.