# Error: "unable to locate package network-manager-vpnc-gui"

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am trying to install vpnc using:

```
sudo apt-get install vpnc network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gui
```

I get an error:

```
unable to locate package network-manager-vpnc-gui
```

I'm not sure what to do. Do I need to add something to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`? Any help is great!

Comment: The package *network-manager-vpnc-gui* doesn not exist in the software repositories and apparently not needed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/488435/cisco-vpn-configuration-steps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct package candidates for the application `vpnc` are `network-manager-vpnc` & `vpnc`. And from the question it also seemed like you need a gui so, the package for that will be `network-manager-vpnc-gnome`.

To install your desired application, type in the command:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install vpnc network-manager-vpnc network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

Comment: @KyleDrummond - You are welcome!

Comment: Not to chat here, but why didn't my command work from earlier? Is it no longer a supported package? Setting up a vpn for my school(cs major so I'll need it when sshing in) and that's what they had listed on a wiki site...

Comment: Your command didn't work simply because you didn't enter the correct package name. E.g.: the correct package name for google chrome is `google-chrome-stable` and not just `google-chrome`. And as for the wiki, it might be old.