# Long list of unmanaged network devices on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04 shows a long list of unmanaged as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

How can I rid of them?

**Update**

This is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
*-network               
     description: Wireless interface
     product: Wireless 7260
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 0
     bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
     logical name: eth0
     version: 6b
     serial: e8:2a:ea:04:76:85
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
     configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-62-generic firmware=17.352738.0 ip=192.168.178.43 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
     resources: irq:35 memory:f7900000-f7901fff
*-network:0
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: 2
     logical name: veth3147af4
     serial: fe:0f:54:7f:0a:41
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:1
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: 3
     logical name: veth7f1acf5
     serial: 12:a0:1c:94:d0:1f
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:2
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: 4
     logical name: veth14f5a2f
     serial: 62:54:a1:28:c3:0d
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:3
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: 5
     logical name: veth0b7948b
     serial: 56:34:6e:7b:ed:df
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:4
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: 6
     logical name: veth8ab848b
     serial: e6:f1:0f:49:92:de
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:5
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: 7
     logical name: veth45b1603
     serial: da:93:8b:14:47:0e
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:6
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: 8
     logical name: veth400bd55
     serial: 12:b3:35:eb:b8:a5
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:7
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: 9
     logical name: veth87dc315
     serial: d6:48:82:7e:02:87
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:8
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: a
     logical name: veth5d4e2cd
     serial: 4e:e7:b0:be:f3:53
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:9
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: b
     logical name: vethb5f8dd4
     serial: c6:79:55:03:4c:b0
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:10
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: c
     logical name: veth1d21db9
     serial: 5e:9a:7d:e5:57:60
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:11
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: d
     logical name: vethee3c0c6
     serial: d6:4b:2b:a1:24:e6
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:12
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: e
     logical name: vethb0b8717
     serial: 9a:f6:b7:cc:65:78
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:13
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: f
     logical name: veth2d5cbbd
     serial: 56:c8:04:43:30:69
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:14
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: 10
     logical name: veth96328b8
     serial: 9a:42:88:49:7b:36
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:15
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: 11
     logical name: vethda512eb
     serial: 9a:e9:21:4a:9d:a0
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:16
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: 12
     logical name: vethf0686f8
     serial: 76:e1:93:37:1f:ae
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:17
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: 13
     logical name: veth9837ad5
     serial: b6:4d:87:47:00:55
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
*-network:18
     description: Ethernet interface
     physical id: 14
     logical name: veth01e210a
     serial: f2:23:a4:9c:68:91
     size: 10Gbit/s
     capabilities: ethernet physical
     configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```

This is the output of `ifconfig`:

```
br-7514c45e53d2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:9e:d4:53:00  
          inet addr:172.23.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:9eff:fed4:5300/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:94 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:892 (892.0 B)  TX bytes:12001 (12.0 KB)

br-86e6dcc5495c Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:f7:ea:bf:79  
          inet addr:172.20.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:f7ff:feea:bf79/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2456 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1900 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:222797 (222.7 KB)  TX bytes:3452963 (3.4 MB)

br-942e7ec9c8d7 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:58:77:01:5c  
          inet addr:172.19.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:58ff:fe77:15c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:200 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:374 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:64296 (64.2 KB)  TX bytes:67571 (67.5 KB)

br-a3c7cefb1b1b Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:59:c1:b7:6b  
          inet addr:172.22.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:59ff:fec1:b76b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1197 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1737 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3359344 (3.3 MB)  TX bytes:180069 (180.0 KB)

br-bd0d56e8c790 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:b3:94:f9:c4  
          inet addr:172.25.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:b3ff:fe94:f9c4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:88 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:536 (536.0 B)  TX bytes:11330 (11.3 KB)

br-dbeb727f6ae7 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:48:78:59:b3  
          inet addr:172.21.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:48ff:fe78:59b3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:385 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:509 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:35970 (35.9 KB)  TX bytes:60587 (60.5 KB)

br-dd77aafc6718 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:d5:53:62:75  
          inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:81:bb:f3:46  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:2a:ea:04:76:85  
          inet addr:192.168.178.43  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1eef:7218:86af:ad70/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5517 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8247871 (8.2 MB)  TX bytes:1493173 (1.4 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1270 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1270 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:187832 (187.8 KB)  TX bytes:187832 (187.8 KB)

veth01e210a Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f2:23:a4:9c:68:91  
          inet6 addr: fe80::f023:a4ff:fe9c:6891/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5976 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5469 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:529485 (529.4 KB)  TX bytes:1090877 (1.0 MB)

veth0b7948b Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 56:34:6e:7b:ed:df  
          inet6 addr: fe80::5434:6eff:fe7b:eddf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:17137 (17.1 KB)

veth14f5a2f Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 62:54:a1:28:c3:0d  
          inet6 addr: fe80::6054:a1ff:fe28:c30d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5232 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1051453 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:517621 (517.6 KB)

veth1d21db9 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5e:9a:7d:e5:57:60  
          inet6 addr: fe80::5c9a:7dff:fee5:5760/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:59 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:279 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6631 (6.6 KB)  TX bytes:28882 (28.8 KB)

veth2d5cbbd Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 56:c8:04:43:30:69  
          inet6 addr: fe80::54c8:4ff:fe43:3069/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:199 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1881 (1.8 KB)  TX bytes:19736 (19.7 KB)

veth3147af4 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:0f:54:7f:0a:41  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc0f:54ff:fe7f:a41/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:289 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:11403 (11.4 KB)  TX bytes:33069 (33.0 KB)

veth400bd55 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:b3:35:eb:b8:a5  
          inet6 addr: fe80::10b3:35ff:feeb:b8a5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:132 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:16292 (16.2 KB)

veth45b1603 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr da:93:8b:14:47:0e  
          inet6 addr: fe80::d893:8bff:fe14:470e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:255 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:415 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:28183 (28.1 KB)  TX bytes:139598 (139.5 KB)

veth5d4e2cd Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4e:e7:b0:be:f3:53  
          inet6 addr: fe80::4ce7:b0ff:febe:f353/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1197 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1781 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:3376102 (3.3 MB)  TX bytes:185031 (185.0 KB)

veth7f1acf5 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:a0:1c:94:d0:1f  
          inet6 addr: fe80::10a0:1cff:fe94:d01f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:345 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:443 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:34387 (34.3 KB)  TX bytes:71193 (71.1 KB)

veth87dc315 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d6:48:82:7e:02:87  
          inet6 addr: fe80::d448:82ff:fe7e:287/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:532 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:609 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:58327 (58.3 KB)  TX bytes:128890 (128.8 KB)

veth8ab848b Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e6:f1:0f:49:92:de  
          inet6 addr: fe80::e4f1:fff:fe49:92de/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:139 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:283 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:15824 (15.8 KB)  TX bytes:58181 (58.1 KB)

veth96328b8 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9a:42:88:49:7b:36  
          inet6 addr: fe80::9842:88ff:fe49:7b36/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:138 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1088 (1.0 KB)  TX bytes:16963 (16.9 KB)

veth9837ad5 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b6:4d:87:47:00:55  
          inet6 addr: fe80::b44d:87ff:fe47:55/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:118 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:268 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:10537 (10.5 KB)  TX bytes:30432 (30.4 KB)

vethb0b8717 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9a:f6:b7:cc:65:78  
          inet6 addr: fe80::98f6:b7ff:fecc:6578/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:476 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:574 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:51285 (51.2 KB)  TX bytes:2986349 (2.9 MB)

vethb5f8dd4 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c6:79:55:03:4c:b0  
          inet6 addr: fe80::c479:55ff:fe03:4cb0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:128 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:314 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12090 (12.0 KB)  TX bytes:34371 (34.3 KB)

vethda512eb Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9a:e9:21:4a:9d:a0  
          inet6 addr: fe80::98e9:21ff:fe4a:9da0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:247 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:337 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:25337 (25.3 KB)  TX bytes:132134 (132.1 KB)

vethee3c0c6 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d6:4b:2b:a1:24:e6  
          inet6 addr: fe80::d44b:2bff:fea1:24e6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:203 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:20091 (20.0 KB)

vethf0686f8 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 76:e1:93:37:1f:ae  
          inet6 addr: fe80::74e1:93ff:fe37:1fae/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:385 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:553 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:41360 (41.3 KB)  TX bytes:65549 (65.5 KB)
```

I just noticed that this list gets populated after starting multiple Docker containers, so it looks like this list is a result of the Docker networking stack.

Comment: Have you installed some other manager, WICD perhaps?

Comment: No, I just installed the `vpnc`-Plugin for Network-Manager

Comment: Does your current ethernet or wireless work? Show us the `terminal` output of `sudo lshw -C network` and `ifconfig`. Edit your question with the results.

Comment: In the future please add relevant information in you question from the start. What you installed/changed **is** relevant. Meanwhile take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/488435/cisco-vpn-configuration-steps

Comment: @heynnema I just updated my question.

Comment: Yes, they're virtual network interfaces created by Docker.

Comment: Is there a way to hide them in Network Manager?

Comment: There's a bug in 16.04 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1458322

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hide virtual / unmanaged networks due to a bug in Network Manager since Ubuntu 15.04: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1458322